# Python - How to replace boolean value if less than a certain number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, boolean, operators

Working on creating my own objects and classes, and am attempting to write a method that will check a number from an object and if found to be less than 50, it will replace the boolean value for another object that has a pre-defined value of False.

Currently I have an if/else statement that checks to see if the value is less than 50 for gamePrice, and if it is, it should change the value for isASteal to True. If greater than 50, it should change to False. The default value for isASteal is set to False, and the default value for gamePrice is 0

```
class videoGames(object):
def __init__(self, gameName = '', gamePrice = 0, isASteal = False):
    self.gameName = gameName
    self.gamePrice = gamePrice
    self.isASteal = isASteal

def gameValue(self):
    if self.gamePrice == 0 or self.gamePrice >= 50:
        self.isASteal = False

    else:
        self.isASteal = True
    fullGames = 'Title:{}\t\ Price: ${}\t\ Steal: {}'.format(self.gameName, self.gamePrice, self.isASteal)

    return fullGames
```

If a user invokes the function by saying:

```
    game1 = videoGames('Call of Duty', 15)
```

they should get an output looking like this:

```
     Title: Call of Duty      Price: $15           Steal: True
```

instead I am getting:

```
     Title: Call of Duty       Price: $15          Steal: False
```

Comment: I ran your code and got the right answer, can you check the question again

Comment: You shouldn't have code in a class that is not in a method. Please check your indentation.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh it  does not work

Comment: Are you doing `print(game1.gameValue())` ? I get the output `Title:Call of Duty \ Price: $15 \ Steal: True`

Comment: no I am doing print(game1)

Comment: You need to call the function on the instance, and not call the class instance itself

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh how can I get it so that I don't have to call the function of the instance? and just call the class instance which would include the function of the instance?

Comment: You can override `__str__()` dunder method for it  @LordQuackingStick Check my answer below :)

Comment: wow thank you so much! is it possible to have more than one __str__() dunder method?

Comment: No only one dunder method per class unfortunately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  want to print the string when you call the instance, you can override the dunder `__str__()` method of the class

```
class videoGames(object):
    def __init__(self, gameName = '', gamePrice = 0, isASteal = False):
        self.gameName = gameName
        self.gamePrice = gamePrice
        self.isASteal = isASteal

    #Overriden ___str__ method
    def __str__(self):
        if self.gamePrice == 0 or self.gamePrice >= 50:
            self.isASteal = False

        else:
            self.isASteal = True
        fullGames = 'Title:{}\t\ Price: ${}\t\ Steal: {}'.format(self.gameName, self.gamePrice, self.isASteal)

        return fullGames

game1 = videoGames('Call of Duty', 15)
print(game1)
```

The output will be

```
Title:Call of Duty   Price: $15  Steal: True
```